# How to change the border colour 'onChangeText' in TextInput Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

So, I was trying to make this nice little TextInput Component where the border colour changes as soon as I start typing and if I clear the text border colour returns to default.

Comment: provide some code if you want help.

Comment: I needed an idea on how to dynamically change property if I click on TextInput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Component **TextInput**. When you write in the textbox, border colour of the textbox will be changed and after clearing text it sets default. Please write a small **css class .myInput** which I wrote in **TextInput.css**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import './TextInput.css'

function TextInput(props) {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState({});

    function textChange(e) {
        if(e.target.value === '')
            setStyle({border: '1px solid gray'});
        else
            setStyle({border: '1px solid red'});
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input className="myInput" style={style} onChange={textChange} type="text"/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TextInput;
```

Here is the css class:

```
.myInput {    
   outline-width: 0; 
}
```